# How to dynamically display a menu with categories/subcategories? for a parent-child relations?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, next.js

I am using nextjs with mongodb for a project.
I have this category model:

```
const CategorySchema = new Schema(
  {
    name: { type: String, required: true },
    parent: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Category' },
    properties: { type: Object },
    path: { type: String },
  },
  { strict: true, timestamps: true }
);

export const CategoryModel =
  models?.Category || model('Category', CategorySchema);
```

The path is to remember the category's ancestors, for example:
if we have `Clothing` as main category with these subcategories:

```
-> `Jeans`
-> `Jackets`
   -> `Winter Jackets`
```

Then Clothing has path null, `Jeans` has path `,Clothing,` , `Jackets` has path `,Clothing,` and `Winter Jackets` has path `,Clothing,Jackets,`

I would like to display them into a list, something like this:

```
**Main category1**
-> Child1
   -> ChildChild1
     ->ChildChildChild1 
   -> ChildChild2
-> Child2
**Main category2**
-> Child1
  -> ChildChild1
```

and so on where is the case.
The depth of children could vary, for example, the depth of one category could be 1 like `Main->Child`, while others could have 3 like `Main->Child->Childchild->Childchildchild`
I tried with this approach, but it gives an hydration failed, and the subcategories are displayed twice:

**page.tsx:**

```
async function Page() {
  const categories = await getCategoryTree();
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Categories:</h1>
      <CategoryList categories={categories} />
    </div>
  );
}

async function getCategoryTree() {
  const client = await clientPromise;
  const db = client.db().collection('categories');
  // Fetch categories from MongoDB (customize this query as needed)
  const categories = await CategoryModel.find().exec();

  const transformedCategories = categories.map((category) => ({
    ...category.toObject(),
    children: categories.filter(
      (child) => child.parent?._id.toString() === category._id.toString()
    ),
  }));

  console.log('transformed::::::');
  console.log(transformedCategories[0].children);
  console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(transformedCategories)));
  return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(transformedCategories));

}

export default Page;
```

**CategoryList.tsx**

```
const CategoryList = ({ categories }: { categories: any[] }) => {
  const renderCategory = (category: any) => {
    return (
      <li key={category._id}>
        {category.name}
        {category.children && (
          <ul>
            {category.children.map((child: any) => (
              <li key={child._id}>{renderCategory(child)}</li>
            ))}
          </ul>
        )}
      </li>
    );
  };

  return (
    <ul>
      {categories.map((category) =>
        category.path === null ? (
          <li key={category._id}>{renderCategory(category)}</li>
        ) : null
      )}
    </ul>
  );
};

export default CategoryList;
```

**EDIT1:**

This is the `categories` object returned from the database with this query:
`const categories = await CategoryModel.find().exec();`

```
[
  {
    _id: new ObjectId('65d488209fa9f36471674dd2'),
    name: 'Clothing',
    path: null
  },
  {
    _id: new ObjectId('65d488839fa9f36471674ddc'),
    name: 'Jeans',
    parent: new ObjectId('65d488209fa9f36471674dd2'),
    path: ',Clothing,'
  },
  {
    _id: new ObjectId('65d489959fa9f36471674def'),
    name: 'Jackets',
    parent: new ObjectId('65d488209fa9f36471674dd2'),
    path: ',Clothing,'
  },
  {
    _id: new ObjectId('65d4899d9fa9f36471674df4'),
    name: 'Winterjackets',
    parent: new ObjectId('65d489959fa9f36471674def'),
    path: ',Clothing,Jackets,'
  },
  {
    _id: new ObjectId('65d514d7878fbc1058f22ef7'),
    name: 'Electronics',
    path: null
  }
]
```

And after this transformation:

```
 const transformedCategories = categories.map((category) => ({
    ...category.toObject(),
    children: categories.filter(
      (child) => child.parent?._id.toString() === category._id.toString()
    ),
  }));

  return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(transformedCategories));
```

The data is this:

```
Clothing [
  {
    _id: '65d488839fa9f36471674ddc',
    name: 'Jeans',
    parent: '65d488209fa9f36471674dd2',
    path: ',Clothing,'
  },
  {
    _id: '65d489959fa9f36471674def',
    name: 'Jackets',
    parent: '65d488209fa9f36471674dd2',
    path: ',Clothing,'
  }
]
Jeans []
Jackets [
  {
    _id: '65d4899d9fa9f36471674df4',
    name: 'Winterjackets',
    parent: '65d489959fa9f36471674def',
    path: ',Clothing,Jackets,'
  }
]
Winterjackets []
Electronics []
```

I did

```
jsoncategories.forEach((cat) => {
    console.log(cat.name, cat.children);
  });
```

to better view each object.

this renderes:

```
Clothing
Jeans
Jackets
Electronics
```

So it seems that this approach works for a depth of 1 like `Main->Child` but for `Main-Child-Child` it doesnt work, because as you can see in the `json parsed` data the `Jackets` child of `Clothing` does not include a `children` field of `winterjackets`, so I think I have to find a recursive solution?

**EDIT2:**
**WORKAROUND**
As mentioned in comments, I found a *workaround* for this by using:

```
const CategoryList = ({ categories }: { categories: any[] }) => {
  categories.forEach((cat) => {
    console.log(cat.name, cat.children);
  });
  const renderCategory = (category: any) => {
    //console.log(category);
    return (
      <>
        {category.name}
        {category.children && (
          <ul>
            {category.children.map((child: any) => (
              <div key={child._id}>
                {renderCategory(categories.find((x) => x._id === child._id))}{' '}
              </div>
            ))}
          </ul>
        )}
      </>
    );
  };

  return (
    <ul>
      {categories.map((category) =>
        category.path === null ? (
          <li key={category._id}>{renderCategory(category)}</li>
        ) : null
      )}
    </ul>
  );
};
```

This works because instead of using

```
{category.children.map((child: any) => (
              <div key={child._id}>
                {renderCategory(child) }{' '}
              </div>
            ))}
```

where the render is called with the child directly, I use

```
{renderCategory(categories.find((x) => x._id === child._id))}
```

thus searching for the next category to display inside the json parsed data, where each category has a children array.

This works but doesn't feel *elegant* as we have to perform a find on every render. This seems like a problem on formatting the JSON data to recursively add the list of children to each category thus forming some sort of tree. So I am open once again for suggestions

Comment: The hydration issue you are getting is because you have a `li` nested inside a `li`, this happens because you're running your `renderCategory` function inside a `li` and then rendering another `li` inside the function. Note that this same error is happening again inside the function. To fix this first part of the problem, remove the `li` tags before calling `renderCategory`. 
About the categories showing twice, I'd need to see the data you're getting from the DB because I tried it with mocked data and it worked for me.

Comment: @ManuelEsperon yes, you're right about the hydration. Also, as you said, this would work if for example my data would be like `[Main1: [children1: [childrenchild1, childrenchild2, etc], children2: [childrenchild3, childrenchild4] ] , Main2: ...]` and so on. But that was part of the question, how can I transform the data like that? Because in my database, I don't store a children array for categories, they only have a parent and the path. I found some _workaround_ but it doesn't seem the best way; I will put my _workaround_ in the edit